# Lightning Component : JS error when closing modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, modal

I'm working on a Lightning Component that open a modal when user click on a button. This modal have the close button on the upper-right side and also two custom button, "Cancel" and "Save". By clicking on one or the other button, the modal closes but an error window pop with this message:

```
[Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null]
getDomWidth()@https://mydomain--1dev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-datatable.js:3134:18
getAvailableWidthFromDom()@https://mydomain--1dev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-datatable.js:3140:10
getExpectedTableWidth()@https://mydomain--1dev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-datatable.js:3035:26
adjustColumnsSize()@https://mydomain--1dev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-datatable.js:2968:30
privateWidthObserver.lightningInputUtils.debounce()@https://mydomain--1dev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-datatable.js:4301:99
eval()@https://mydomain--1dev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-input-utils.js:154:12
```

I try several solution to close my modal in my helper but they all launch this error:

```
saveRecords : function(component, event, helper){
    var saveAction = component.get("c.saveRecord");
    saveAction.setParams({
        opp: component.get("v.opp"),
        oppCnt: component.get("v.contact"),
        oppCntList: component.get("v.OppContRoles")
    });
    saveAction.setCallback(this, function(a){
        if(a.getState() == "SUCCESS"){
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            navEvt.setParams({
                "recordId": component.get("v.recordId"),
                "slideDevName": "related"
            });
            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
            navEvt.fire();

            helper.showSuccessToast(component, event, helper);
        }
        else{
            component.set("v.errorMessage",true);
            var btnClicked = event.getSource();
            btnClicked.set("v.disabled",false);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
},
```

Also this one:

```
var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction"); 
            dismissActionPanel.fire();
```

And this one:

```
component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose();
```

I didn't find other possible way to close my modal and prevent this error.

Thank you in advance,

Miopau

**EDIT** : Here is my cmp code:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,lightning:actionOverride" controller="SMB_Opp_Edit_Account_Contact_Handler" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/> 
<!-- General variables -->
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="opp" type="Opportunity" />
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="OpportunityContactRole"/>
<aura:attribute name="OppContRoles" type="String[]" />
<aura:attribute name="legalPicklists" type="String[]" />
<aura:attribute name="legalValue" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="industryPicklists" type="String[]" />
<aura:attribute name="industryValue" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="salutationPicklists" type="String[]" />
<aura:attribute name="errorMessage" type="Boolean"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.opp}" action="{!c.checkAccountData}"/>


<form class="slds-form--stacked">
    <div class="slds-col modal-header slds-modal__header">
        <h2 class="title slds-text-heading--medium">Account and Contact</h2>
        <h3 class="title slds-text-heading--small">Edit Account and Contact informations</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col modal-body scrollable slds-p-around--medium" >
        <div class="slds-grid" style="margin-bottom:15px">
            <div class="slds-col" style="margin:10px">
                <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                    <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                        <div class="slds-media__figure">
                            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="account">
                                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:account" size="medium"/>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">                       
                            <span class="slds-text-heading_small"><b>Account Informations</b></span>                       
                        </h2>
                    </header>
                </div>

                <lightning:select   label="Select a legal form" aura:id="accForm" value="{!v.opp.Account.Legal_Form__c}">
                    <option value=""> -- None --</option>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.legalPicklists}" var="item">
                        <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}"></option> 
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>

                <lightning:input type="text" label="Commercial/Trading Name" value="{!v.opp.Account.CommercialTradingName__c}" aura:id="accForm" />
                <lightning:input type="text" label="Compagny Name" value="{!v.opp.Account.Name}" aura:id="accForm" required="true"/>
                <lightning:input type="text" label="Merchant Category Code" value="{!v.opp.Account.CodeMCC__c}" aura:id="accForm"/>
                <lightning:input type="Integer" maxlength="18" label="Company Turnover" value="{!v.opp.Account.Company_Turnover_Y_1__c}" aura:id="accForm" />

                <lightning:select   label="Select a Market Segment" aura:id="accForm" value="{!v.opp.Account.Industry}" >
                    <option value=""> -- None --</option>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.industryPicklists}" var="item">
                        <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}"></option> 
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
                <lightning:input type="text" label="VAT Number" maxlength="9" value="{!v.opp.Account.VAT_Number__c}" placeholder="xxxxxxxxx" aura:id="accForm" pattern="[0-9]{9}"/>
                <lightning:input type="text" maxlength="11" label="National Tax Number" value="{!v.opp.Account.National_Tax_Number__c}" aura:id="accForm" />
                <br/>
                <p><b>Address:</b></p>
                <lightning:input type="text" label="Street" value="{!v.opp.Account.BillingStreet}" aura:id="accForm" />
                <lightning:input type="text" label="Post Code" value="{!v.opp.Account.BillingPostalCode}" aura:id="accForm" />
                <lightning:input type="text" label="City" value="{!v.opp.Account.BillingCity}" aura:id="accForm" />
                <br/>
                <lightning:input type="tel" label="Phone" value="{!v.opp.Account.Phone}" aura:id="accForm" />
                <lightning:input type="email" label="Company Email" value="{!v.opp.Account.Company_Email__c}" aura:id="accForm" pattern="([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9_\+\.]*[a-z0-9])@([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9\.]*[a-z0-9]\.(arpa|root|aero|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)|([0-9]{1,3}\.{3}[0-9]{1,3}))" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Incorrect Email Format"/>
                <lightning:input type="text" maxlength="14" label="Creditor ID" value="{!v.opp.Account.Creditor_ID__c}" aura:id="accForm" />
                <lightning:input type="text"  maxlength="4" label="Founding Year" value="{!v.opp.Account.Founding_year__c}" placeholder="xxxx" aura:id="accForm" pattern="[12][890][0-9][0-9]"  messageWhenPatternMismatch="Year is invalid"/>
                <lightning:input type="Integer" maxlength = "12" label="BIC" value="{!v.opp.Account.BIC__c}" aura:id="accForm" />
                <lightning:input type="text" maxlength="30" label="IBAN" value="{!v.opp.Account.IBAN__c}" placeholder="DExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" aura:id="accIBAN" pattern="DE[0-9]{20}" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Your IBAN format does not meet the German standard."/>
                <lightning:input type="text" maxlength="30" label="IBAN Debit" value="{!v.opp.Account.IBAN_Debit__c}" placeholder="DExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" aura:id="accForm" pattern="DE[0-9]{20}" messageWhenPatternMismatch="Your IBAN format does not meet the German standard."/>
                <lightning:input type="text" label="Bank Account Owner" value="{!v.opp.Account.Bank_Account__c}" aura:id="accForm" required="true"/>

                <br/>

                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.contact != null}">
                    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid slds-border_top">
                        <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                                <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-contact" title="contact">
                                    <lightning:icon iconName="standard:contact" size="medium"/>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-media__body">
                                <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">                       
                                    <span class="slds-text-heading_small"><b>Primary Contact:&nbsp;{!v.contact.Contact.FirstName}&nbsp;{!v.contact.Contact.LastName}</b></span>                       
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                    </div>


                    <lightning:select   label="Salutation" aura:id="accForm" value="{!v.contact.Contact.Salutation}" required="true">
                        <option value=""> -- None --</option>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.salutationPicklists}" var="item">
                            <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}"></option> 
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>

                    <lightning:input type="text" label="First Name" value="{!v.contact.Contact.FirstName}" aura:id="accForm"/>
                    <lightning:input type="text" label="Last Name" value="{!v.contact.Contact.LastName}" aura:id="accForm" required="true"/>
                    <lightning:input type="date" label="Birthdate" value="{!v.contact.Contact.Birthdate}" aura:id="accForm" required="true"/>
                    <lightning:input type="text" maxlength="128" label="Job Title" value="{!v.contact.Contact.Title}" aura:id="accForm"/>
                    <lightning:input type="text" maxlength="128" label="Place of Birth" value="{!v.contact.Contact.Place_of_Birth__c}" aura:id="accForm"/>
                    <lightning:input type="text" maxlength="128" label="Nationality" value="{!v.contact.Contact.Nationality__c}" aura:id="accForm"/>
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid slds-border_top">
                            <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-error" title="Error">
                                        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:error" size="medium" variant="Error"/>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-media__body">
                                    <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">                       
                                        <span class="slds-text-heading_small"><b>You have no Primary Contact, please add one before trying to update informations.</b></span>                       
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </header>
                        </div>
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.OppContRoles}" var="item">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!item.taux != null}">
                        <br/>
                        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid slds-border_top">
                            <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-contact" title="contact">
                                        <lightning:icon iconName="standard:contact" size="medium"/>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-media__body">
                                    <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">                       
                                        <span class="slds-text-heading_small"><b>Owner Contact:&nbsp;{!item.Contact.FirstName}&nbsp;{!item.Contact.LastName}</b></span>                       
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </header>
                        </div>

                        <lightning:select   label="Salutation" aura:id="accForm" value="{!item.Contact.Salutation}" required="true">
                            <option value=""> -- None --</option>
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.salutationPicklists}" var="item">
                                <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}"></option> 
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </lightning:select>

                        <lightning:input type="text" label="First Name" value="{!item.Contact.FirstName}" aura:id="accForm"/>
                        <lightning:input type="text" label="Last Name" value="{!item.Contact.LastName}" aura:id="accForm" required="true"/>
                        <lightning:input type="date" label="Birthdate" value="{!item.Contact.Birthdate}" aura:id="accForm"/>
                        <lightning:input type="text" label="Job Title" value="{!item.Contact.Title}" aura:id="accForm"/>
                    </aura:if>
                </aura:iteration>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.errorMessage}">
    <span style="color:red;">Incorrect fields values, please update them before update records.</span>
</aura:if>
<div style="background-color:white;" class="slds-modal__footer slds-align_absolute-center">        
    <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancel}" />      
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" aura:id="buttonSave" onclick="{!c.save}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post complete code? do you have a table in your modal? It have tried your code for a simple modal and it works

Comment: Here it is, I edit my post.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you have `lightning:overlayLibrary` if you're not creating a modal from that? From the markup it looks like you're opening a quick action styled like a modal, but you want on finish of this component you want to close the quick action right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try just show/hiding the modal using slds classes:

So the modal would look something like this

```
<div aura:id="myModal">
<div class="slds-modal__footer">
<lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.handleCancelModal}" />
</div>
</div>
```

and then the onclick would add slds-hide to it

```
handleCancelModal: function (component, event, helper) {
        var confirmmodal = component.find('myModal');
        $A.util.addClass(confirmmodal, 'slds-hide');
    },
```

Comment: Is this "way to do" a good way? I mean what if my users open the modal, then "close/hide it" and repeat this operation several times? I will have several modal open but hide?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you can start with the modal hidden, and then use a remove class to show it, and hide it on cancel as shown above.  That way, there should only every be one modal that you are creating/displaying. Any other buttons can just have handlers for any actions you need to take.  I considered a child component but you can up needing events for communication and my modal use case was really just a click and move on, or cancel and go back scenario, so seemed easiest to go down this route so that it was all contained within the main component

Comment: Ok! It makes sense. I will consider it as an alternative solution if I can't find any way to resolve my problem because this will require some modifications but thank you very much!